# HTTP 400 error when URL is called in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my activity, I get email and password from user using EditTexts and then I add them to a JsonObject variable. I convert this variable to string and send this string as body in my POST request to the API. However, I got 400 error with null response body. Here is the related code:

Login activity:

```
email = findViewById(R.id.edt_login_email);
password = findViewById(R.id.edt_login_password);
linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_login);

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.thinghub.io/v0/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
final WebService webService = retrofit.create(WebService.class);

final Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn_login_login);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        emailToString = email.getText().toString();
        passwordToString = password.getText().toString();

        JsonObject userDetail = new JsonObject();
        userDetail.addProperty("mail", emailToString);
        userDetail.addProperty("password", passwordToString);
        Log.d(TAG, userDetail.toString());

        Call <JsonResponse> call = webService.login(userDetail.toString());
        call.enqueue(new Callback < JsonResponse > () {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponse> call, Response<JsonResponse> response) {

                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response.code()));
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response.body()));
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response.headers()));

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Succsessful login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // token = response.body().getUuid();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    SharedPreferences userDetails = (LoginActivity.this).getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
                    edit.putString("mail", emailToString);
                    edit.putString("token", token);
                    edit.apply();
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    TextView mTitle = new TextView(LoginActivity.this);
                    mTitle.setText("NO RESPONSE GET");
                    mTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    mTitle.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

                    new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(LoginActivity.this)
                        .setCustomTitle(mTitle)
                        .setMessage("username or password is wrong")
                        .setPositiveButton("try again", null)
                        .show();
                }
            }
        });
```

WebService interface:

```
public interface WebService {

    @POST("token")
    Call<JsonResponse> login(@Body String body);
}
```

JsonResponse class:

```
public class JsonResponse {
    private String string;

    public JsonResponse(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

I get this log output:

```
D/UDJ: {"mail":"ghasemi@test.com","password":"123123"}
D/UDJ: 400
D/UDJ: null
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: 400 is a server side BAD REQUEST error.  We'd need the server side code to answer you.  It could be as simple as you have the URL wrong, or it could be something like a missing/incorrectly named parameter.  But we can't really tell you.

Comment: @GabeSechan  you can test it in postman and you get correct json resonse 
url is :  http://api.thinghub.io/v0/token
and row body is : {"mail":"ghasemi@test.com","password":"123123"}

test is via Post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call retrofit like below

```
JsonObject userDetail = new JsonObject();

userDetail.addProperty("mail", emailToString);
userDetail.addProperty("password", passwordToString);

Log.d(TAG, userDetail.toString());

Call <JsonResponse> call = webService.login(userDetail);

call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonResponse> () {

   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponse> call, Response <JsonResponse> response) {

    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response.code()));
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response.body()));
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response.headers()));

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Succsessful login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     // token = response.body().getUuid();
     Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
     SharedPreferences userDetails = (LoginActivity.this).getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
     edit.putString("mail", emailToString);
     edit.putString("token", token);
     edit.apply();
     startActivity(intent);

    } else {



     TextView mTitle = new TextView(LoginActivity.this);
     mTitle.setText("NO RESPONSE GET");
     mTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     mTitle.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

     new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(LoginActivity.this)
      .setCustomTitle(mTitle)
      .setMessage("username or password is wrong")
      .setPositiveButton("try again", null)
      .show();


    }
   }
```

Interface is:

```
public interface WebService {
       @POST("token")
       Call<JsonResponse> login(@Body JsonObject body);
}
```

Comment: whats the different ?

Comment: `webService.login(userDetail)` instead of `webService.login(userDetail.toString())` plus `login(@Body JsonObject body)` instead of `login(@Body String body)`

Answer (score 0):

@Hengameh, I believe the error you get is because you are sending the request object as a string. What you want is send the data class as is to Retrofit and then Retrofit does the job of converting it to json.
Create a request class follows.

```
class LoginRequest{
String mail;
String password;}
```

Now instead of

```
 JsonObject userDetail = new JsonObject();
userDetail.addProperty("mail", emailToString);
userDetail.addProperty("password",passwordToString);
```

Add

```
LoginRequest userDetail = new LoginRequest();

        userDetail.mail = emailToString;
        userDetail.password = passwordToString;
```

Modify interface as

```
public interface WebService {

@POST("token")
Call<JsonResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest body);
}
```

And call should be

```
Call<JsonResponse> call = webService.login(userDetail);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Retrofit, there is no converter for String by default. That's why you are not sending a proper request. However, since you added GSON converter, you can pass `userDetail` JsonObject directly to the `login()` function:

```
JsonObject userDetail = new JsonObject();
userDetail.addProperty("mail", "ghasemi@test.com");
userDetail.addProperty("password", "123123");
Log.d(TAG, userDetail.toString());

Call<JsonResponse> call = webService.login(userDetail);
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonResponse>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponse> call, Response<JsonResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Successful login");
            JsonResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            // Use login data here...
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unsuccessful login");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failure!");
    }
});
```

If you still want to provide body as string, you need to add scalar-converter library to your app gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
```

...and then add it to your Retrofit instance as follows:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.thinghub.io/v0/")
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Your string will be added successfully as body in your request now.

---

You need these POJO classes in both cases:

JsonResponse.java

```
public class JsonResponse {
    @SerializedName("uuid")
    @Expose
    private String uuid;
    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    private String user;
    @SerializedName("createdAt")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("expiresAt")
    @Expose
    private String expiresAt;
    @SerializedName("detail")
    @Expose
    private Detail detail;
    @SerializedName("lastAccessAt")
    @Expose
    private Object lastAccessAt;
    @SerializedName("suspendedOrgs")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> suspendedOrgs = null;

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getExpiresAt() {
        return expiresAt;
    }

    public void setExpiresAt(String expiresAt) {
        this.expiresAt = expiresAt;
    }

    public Detail getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(Detail detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public Object getLastAccessAt() {
        return lastAccessAt;
    }

    public void setLastAccessAt(Object lastAccessAt) {
        this.lastAccessAt = lastAccessAt;
    }

    public List<Object> getSuspendedOrgs() {
        return suspendedOrgs;
    }

    public void setSuspendedOrgs(List<Object> suspendedOrgs) {
        this.suspendedOrgs = suspendedOrgs;
    }
}
```

Detail.java

```
public class Detail {

    @SerializedName("ip-address")
    @Expose
    private String ipAddress;
    @SerializedName("user-agent")
    @Expose
    private String userAgent;
    @SerializedName("x-forwarded-for")
    @Expose
    private String xForwardedFor;
    @SerializedName("accept-language")
    @Expose
    private Object acceptLanguage;
    @SerializedName("visitor-country")
    @Expose
    private String visitorCountry;

    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }

    public String getUserAgent() {
        return userAgent;
    }

    public void setUserAgent(String userAgent) {
        this.userAgent = userAgent;
    }

    public String getXForwardedFor() {
        return xForwardedFor;
    }

    public void setXForwardedFor(String xForwardedFor) {
        this.xForwardedFor = xForwardedFor;
    }

    public Object getAcceptLanguage() {
        return acceptLanguage;
    }

    public void setAcceptLanguage(Object acceptLanguage) {
        this.acceptLanguage = acceptLanguage;
    }

    public String getVisitorCountry() {
        return visitorCountry;
    }

    public void setVisitorCountry(String visitorCountry) {
        this.visitorCountry = visitorCountry;
    }
}
```

Comment: i didnt need Pojo or detail class but you are right i need this line :
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())